# QuantLib building error

Tags: c++, build, visual-studio-2015, quantlib

I am trying to build `QuantLib` but, when running the build process, it returns with 18 succesfull and 1 failed (out of 19 projects in the solution). The one that fails should be `testsuite`. I am building a `x64` release according to its website instruction. I have tried to build a `Win32` but it is still the same.

I cannot attach output because it is too big, but I can link the output txt file [here](http://pastebin.com/wfRQTQjZ).

My boost version is 1.59 and it is working. I have tested it with several different codes and it compiles without any trouble.

I use Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/lballabio/quantlib/pull/292/files?diff=split

This definitively fix the issue. It is an already known bug.

Comment: Yes, it's a known problem with Boost 1.59 (which still wasn't out at the time of our last release, so we couldn't prevent it.)  I'll probably make a bug-fix release next week that includes the patch linked in the answer. In the meantime, you can either apply the patch yourself or use Boost 1.58.

Comment: @LuigiBallabio Thank you mr. Ballabio. I have already fixed the issue according to your indications posted on GitHub. Many thanks for this wonderful financial tool anyway! It is awesome! Hope to help in some way.